# Formulate linear constraint in AMPL

Tags: optimization, constraints, ampl

I am trying to solve the exercises from *AMPL: A Modeling Language for Math Programming Package*, but I am stuck on Exercise 1-4(e). My code so far looks like this:

.mod-file:

```
# Set of cars we can produce
set CAR;

# Parameters 
param amount {CAR} > 0;     # Amount of cars produced (for each car in CAR)
param time {CAR} > 0;       # Time it takes to produce (for each car in CAR) in hours
param fac_time > 0;         # Factory-time to use next week
param profit {CAR} > 0;     # Profit (for each car in CAR)
param lower {CAR} >= 0;     # Lower limit of amount of cars to be produced (for each car in CAR)

# Define var
var Make {c in CAR} >= lower[c];

# Obj. function
maximize Total_Cars: sum {c in CAR} Make[c];

# Constraits
s.t. Time: sum {c in CAR} time[c] * Make[c] = fac_time;
```

.dat-file:

```
set CAR := T C L; 

param:  time    profit  lower :=
    T   1       200     10      
    C   2       500     20      
    L   3       700     15    ;     
    
param fac_time := 120;
```

The task:

> Each kind of car achieves a certain fuel efficiency, and the manufacturer is required by law to
> maintain a certain ‘‘fleet average’’ efficiency. The fleet average is computed by multiplying the
> efficiency of each kind of car times the number of that kind produced, summing all of the resulting
> products, and dividing by the total of all cars produced. Extend your AMPL model to contain a
> minimum fleet average efficiency constraint. Rearrange the constraint as necessary to make it linear — no variables divided into other variables.

So I changed my code to this:

.mod-file:

```
# Set of cars we can produce
set CAR;

# Parameters 
param amount {CAR} > 0;     # Amount of cars produced (for each car in CAR)
param time {CAR} > 0;       # Time it takes to produce (for each car in CAR) in hours
param fac_time > 0;         # Factory-time to use next week
param profit {CAR} > 0;     # Profit (for each car in CAR)
param lower {CAR} >= 0;     # Lower limit of amount of cars to be produced (for each car in CAR)
param fuel_eff {CAR} > 0;   # Fuel efficiency (for each car in CAR)
param fleet_avg > 0;        # Fleet average efficiency

# Define var
var Make {c in CAR} >= lower[c];

# Obj. function
maximize Total_Cars: sum {c in CAR} Make[c];

# Constraits
s.t. Time: sum {c in CAR} time[c] * Make[c] = fac_time;
s.t. Efficiency:  **HERE** >= fleet_avg;
```

.dat-file:

```
set CAR := T C L; 

param:  time    profit  lower   fuel_eff:=
    T   1       200     10      
    C   2       500     20      
    L   3       700     15              ;       
    
param fac_time := 120;
param fleet_eff := (sum {c in CAR} amount[c] * fuel_eff[c])/Total_Cars;
```

I do not have access to the solutions so my question here is: What should be written inside the constraint for efficiency? Have I defined the parameter `fleet_avg` correctly? If not, what is the proper way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

Your efficiency constraint is mathematically correct.  You don't say so in the problem, but I think it is assumed that `Total Cars` is a variable, just the sum of `Make[c]`, correct?

*So what's the problem then?*

Well you have just made your linear program non-linear by dividing by total cars because you have a variable divided by another variable in that fraction.  (Aside:  remember we are only talking about "linear" in terms of the variables so we want to avoid dividing, multiply variables with each other...  parameters are fixed and are fair game).

*So what's the fix?*

They hint at this in the text by reminding you not to do what you just did above.  Realize that with a little algebra, we can multiply both sides of that equation by `Total Cars` (or more accurately `sum(Make[c])` to get rid of the division...  So I would expect something like this (in pseudocode):

```
sum(Make[c]) * fleet_efficiency >= sum(Make[c] * fuel_eff[c])
```

Which is linear in terms of the variables.